# How to generate set strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string

Trying to generate a set of strings such as 'TCP', 'DNS' or 'SQL'
I want to be able to have these strings set and be able to have them appear randomly like you would with random numbers.

Comment: Please specify what do you mean by 'set strings'. Are they all three-letter computer terminologies?

Comment: Just use an array and Math.random to choose and index, for example `['TCP', 'DNS', 'SQL'][Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]`.

Comment: Shuffle the array and when adding a question better to add your code snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array and select them randomly:

```js
const strings = ['TCP', 'DNS', 'SQL'];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(`Random string: ${strings[Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length)]}`);
}
```